# GridLayout in ScrollView - NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am new to NativeScript. I have 4 images in my page and I want to achieve this.

[image]

Except I want my cover image to be of full-height of the screen. This is the code I'm trying.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout height="100%" width="100%">
      <GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="5*, *, *">
        <StackLayout
          :row="0"
          :col="0"
          :colSpan="2"
          class="bgImage coverImage"
          :style="{backgroundImage:`url('${defaultImg}')`}"
        ></StackLayout>
        <StackLayout
          :row="calcRow(idx)"
          :col="calcCol(idx)"
          :colSpan="idx==0?2:1"
          v-for="(item,idx) in event.imgs"
          :key="idx"
          class="bgImage eventImage"
          :style="{backgroundImage:`url('${item}')`}"
        ></StackLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

If I didn't give height="100%" to StackLayout it's not even loading the images. If I do give it then there is no scroll.

Here is the playground link [Playground Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=cRGZRW)

Comment: playground will be helpful to debug.

Comment: Updated the question with playground link.

Comment: It is showing exactly same as your photo in the question. What do you want to achive here? Redish Tree pic(sun in backdrop ) to be displayed full screen and other four as overlay ?

Comment: Red image to have full screen and other images to be below it when you scroll.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=cRGZRW&v=2

Comment: Ya. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: that is an awesome solution @Manoj. Please put it in the answers so it can be accepted and bumped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `layoutChanged` event of your `ScrollView`  where you may calculate the height of it and use it as height for the first image.

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=cRGZRW&v=2)